# Python задача "Большие буквы"

Tags: python, python-3.x

Условия задачи, перевести первую букву каждого слова в верхний регистр

Суть вопроса в том, что при пошаговом воспроизведении кода, ошибок не наблюдается до момента `replace` на моменте `lips` вместо `Lips` возвращает `lIps`. В любых других случаях отрабатывает правильно. Вопрос, кто может объяснить почему реплейсится не правильное значение?

```py
s = 'i wanna taste you but your lips are venomous poison'


def capitalize(z):
    t = z.split()
    print(t)
    for y in t:
        g = y[0].upper() + y[1:]
        z = z.replace(y, g)
    return z

print(capitalize(s))
```

Comment: `' '.join([i for i in map(lambda x: f'{x[0].upper()}{x[1::]}', s.split())])` - плохой и не оптимизированый вариант, но красиво выглядит :)

Comment: `" ".join(map(str.capitalize, s.split()))`.

Answer (score 1):

У вас на первой итерации все `i` заменяются на `I`, а не только первое слово. Делайте так:

```
s = 'i wanna taste you but your lips are venomous poison'

def capitalize(z):
    t = z.split()
    for i in range(len(t)):
        g = t[i][0].upper() + t[i][1:]
        t[i] = g
    return ' '.join(t)

print(capitalize(s))
```

Или ещё проще:

```
s = 'i wanna taste you but your lips are venomous poison'

print(s.title())
```

Answer (score 0):

У метода `replace`, есть ещё одно значение помимо заменяемого слова и нового слова. Это количество заменяемых слов `string.replace(old, new[, maxcount])`.

В вашем примере оно бесконечное, его необходимо заменить на одно: `(word, g, 1)`

Answer (score 0):

Метод `capitalize()` уже существует у строк. Можно его использовать

```py
def capitalize_first(z):
    result = [i.capitalize() for i in a.split()]
    return " ".join(result)
```

Вывод

```py
>>> a = 'i wanna taste you, but your lips. are venomous poison'
>>> capitalize_first(a) 
'I Wanna Taste You, But Your Lips. Are Venomous Poison'
```